# ABCPdf embeded custom fonts not working when converting html to pdf

Tags: fonts, abcpdf

I am trying to render a PDF from html using ABCPdf. The css contains custom fonts. I have followed the instructions ([Using @font-face with ABCPDF? Or other way of getting fonts into PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020072/using-font-face-with-abcpdf-or-other-way-of-getting-fonts-into-pdf) and [EmbedFont Function](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/doc/1-methods/embedfont.htm)) and I have managed to achieve some level of success by doing the following:

1. Install the fonts on the server that generates the PDF and reboot.
2. Remove all @font-face css command.
3. Call the EmbedFont method. As follows.

   ```
   pdfDoc.Font = pdfDoc.EmbedFont("icomoon Regular", LanguageType.Latin);
   pdfDoc.Font = pdfDoc.EmbedFont("Open Sans Bold", LanguageType.Latin);
   pdfDoc.Font = pdfDoc.EmbedFont("Open Sans Bold Italic", LanguageType.Latin);
   pdfDoc.Font = pdfDoc.EmbedFont("Open Sans Extrabold", LanguageType.Latin);
   pdfDoc.Font = pdfDoc.EmbedFont("Open Sans Extrabold Italic", LanguageType.Latin);
   pdfDoc.Font = pdfDoc.EmbedFont("Open Sans Italic", LanguageType.Latin);
   pdfDoc.Font = pdfDoc.EmbedFont("Open Sans Light", LanguageType.Latin);
   pdfDoc.Font = pdfDoc.EmbedFont("Open Sans Light Italic", LanguageType.Latin);
   pdfDoc.Font = pdfDoc.EmbedFont("Open Sans Regular", LanguageType.Latin);
   pdfDoc.Font = pdfDoc.EmbedFont("Open Sans Semibold", LanguageType.Latin);
   pdfDoc.Font = pdfDoc.EmbedFont("Open Sans Semibold Italic", LanguageType.Latin);
   pdfDoc.Font = pdfDoc.EmbedFont("Sanchez Italic", LanguageType.Latin);
   pdfDoc.Font = pdfDoc.EmbedFont("Sanchez Regular", LanguageType.Latin);
   ```
4. I am using Gecko engine and pdfDoc.AddImageHtml(html, false, documentWidth, true) to render the pdf

If I view PDF on a computer that has the font installed, it works correctly.

If I view the PDF on a computer that does **not** have the font installed, only the first font works (icomoon Regular). Why?

Answer (score 0):

I actually did not need the fonts in the end but I believe the issue could have been solved by setting

```
pdfDoc.HtmlOptions.FontProtection = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this right by adding those two options:

```
doc.HtmlOptions.FontEmbed = true;
doc.HtmlOptions.FontProtection = false;
```

I had only one special font (icomoon).